# Apple WatchKit: No matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I built an AppleWatch-App and can run it successfully in iOS-Simulator.
But when i want to being run it on real watch-device, the following error occured:

> Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No
>   provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate
>   and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier
>   “com.xxxx.yyyyyy.watchkitapp.watchkitextension” were found.

I created an app-identifier for com.xxxx.yyyyyy and i am able to use it for applications. Adding a second app-identifier for “com.xxxx.yyyyyy.watchkitapp.watchkitextension” is not possible at Apple Developer Member Center, because it displays an error:

> "An App ID with Identifier
>   'com.xxxx.yyyyyyyy.watchkitapp.watchkitextension' is not available.
>   Please enter a different string."

What should I do now? Is it required to have two different app identifiers for both targets (the iphone-target and the watchkit-target), or even the third target for "watchkit-extension"?

How to deal with all that targets? My goal is to being able to run my watch-app on a real apple watch...

Comment: You have to create 3 provisioning profiles for 3 targets. That's what I did and it works.